# Facebook SDK for PHP active access token error

Tags: php, facebook

Using this simple code here:

http://pastebin.com/Rfa2F9Db

I get loginUrl fine, and when I click the link I am presented with the authentication page on facebook. I then allow access and get redirected back to my page.

I notice the URL params it has added (including the 'code' one).

However I keep getting the FacebookApiException being fired once I am authenticated with the app with the error:

```
[error] => Array
(
    [message] => An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
    [type] => OAuthException
    [code] => 2500
)
```

I've tried dumping $facebook->getAccessToken() and I can see the token it is using, so why do I keep getting the active access token error message above?

Edit:

Here is the exception trace:

http://pastebin.com/1at6zgKC

One interesting part is [trace:Exception:private][2][args][0][0][accessToken:protected] is empty!

Comment: What do you get if you use `$facebook->api('/me', 'GET')`? That is what is used in the [Facebook API examples](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/). Also, I assume the user is logged in?

Comment: Thanks for replying, same error, and yes the user is logged in.

Comment: make sure you're using the same app_id if you instantiate $facebook more than once.

Comment: Yer I am, just using 1 page, full code is in the link above, trying to get past this first hurdle before I worry about moving it into my classes!

Comment: Do any of the examples in the API documentation work?

Comment: Plz confirm you are using sdk version 3. Also try adding 'cookie' => true